# joomla "SEF" and "unicode alias" not works on windows

Tags: joomla

When I use "SEF" and choice use "unicode alias" in Joomla 1.7

Every thing is ok in godaddy linux server.

But when I move those to windows server even I don't use 'url rewrite' click the link on home page just see 404 page.

I still want to use 'unicode alias' and SEF. How can I fix that?